# Twitter bootstrap time picker on GAEJ

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I'm developing a web app on Google App Engine Java, and I'm using Twitter Bootstrap on my JSP's.

I want to to use a time picker, on my forms, specifically [this one](http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/).
Is it possible to use this, by simple including dependencies?

```
<link type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.autotype.js"></script>, and of course,query and bootstrap, but it does not work...


<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
<input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#timepicker1').timepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: what makes you think it does not work ? Did you try ? What difference does it make that this is running on GAE ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all these 3 files are in your [war directory](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles) and you can access them directly from the browser. Once you have that then you should point to the right path, and it should look something like this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.autotype.js"></script>
```

If you decide to put them in separate directories then include the respective directory name in the path.

Comment: Solved, the thing not working was 'collapse' between calendar/timepicker. Had a conflicting js file(bootbox.js).
My confusion was related due to having to install some sort of dependency/extension on server side, where some GAE restriction may apply.